# Meteor + React: Append response to DOM after a Meteor.call?

Tags: dom, meteor, reactjs

I am super new to React and quite new to Meteor.

I am doing a Meteor.call to a function ('getTheThing'). That function is fetching some information and returns the information as a response. In my browser I can see that the method is returning the correct information (a string), but how do I get that response into the DOM?

(As you can see, I have tried to place it in the DOM with the use of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.result).html(response);`, but then I get this error in my console: `Exception in delivering result of invoking 'getTheThing': TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined`)

```
App = React.createClass({

  findTheThing(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var username = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value.trim();

    Meteor.call("getTheThing", username, function(error, response){
      console.log(response);
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.result).html(response);
    });

    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value = "";
  },

  render(){
    return(
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <div className="landing-container">
              <form className="username" onSubmit={this.findTheThing} >
                <input
                  type="text"
                  ref="textInput"
                  placeholder="what's your username?"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
            <div ref="result">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is under the different context, thus does not contain the `refs` there. Also, you cannot set `html` for the `Dom Element`. You need to change into `Jquery element`

```
    var _this = this;
    Meteor.call("getTheThing", username, function(error, response){
      console.log(response);
      $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(_this.refs.result)).html(response);
    });
```

Though i recommend you to set the response into the state and let the component re-rendered

For a complete React way

```
App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
      return { result: "" };
  },
  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps: any, nextState: any): boolean {
      return (nextState['result'] !== this.state['result']);
  },
  findTheThing(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var username = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value.trim();

    Meteor.call("getTheThing", username, function(error, response){
      console.log(response);
      _this.setState({ result: response });
    });

    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value = "";
  },

  render(){
    return(
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <div className="landing-container">
              <form className="username" onSubmit={this.findTheThing} >
                <input
                  type="text"
                  ref="textInput"
                  placeholder="what's your username?"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
            <div ref="result">{this.state['result']}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there anyway I can do this without the use of jquery? What do you mean with `Though i recommend you to set the response into the state and let the component re-rendered`?